# Visual Composer Not working After Changing Site URL to www.* in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, error-handling, wordpress

I am having a wordpress site .I have Changed my site url in phpmyadmin from example.com to www.example.com . But i noticed everything else is working but the pages created using Visual Composer plugin are not opening and pages are only opening in Classic Mode of Editing and No option to open page in Backend Editor or Frontend editor

There is one weird thing I mentioned that when i have changed website url from example.com to www.example.com only then this problem occurs

But when I again rollback it from www.example.com to example.com then visual composer works fine . Is there any other place where i need to make changes

Comment: It depends on how you made the host change.  If you just changed the fields in the `wp_options` table, you may have missed others.  Alternatively, you may have updated some PHP-serialiazed fields, and broken the serialization (as it includes the string length, which will have changed).  I'd try rolling back your update, then reapplying it using the "[Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)" mentioned in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), which will do it properly

Comment: @Hobo there is one weird thing I mentioned that when i have changed website url from example.com to www.example.com only then this problem occurs --------But when I again rollback it from www.example.com to example.com then visual composer works fine . Is there any other place where i need to make changes

Comment: Probably lots.  Use the search and replace script I linked (you can find it in the ["Moving WordPress" Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) if you don't trust the direct link), which'll do it properly.  Back your database up first, of course.  I've never had a problem using it, but why tempt fate?

Comment: @Hobo Thanks i am going to try it

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: @Hobo sorry i can check after some time

Answer (score 0):

Without going into a rabbit hole, this issue is caused by the length of your URL.

Adding a line to the .htaccess file should solve your issue, as Visual Composer (now WPBakery) can't cope with URLs longer than a certain length.

```
SubstituteMaxLineLength 30m
```